# Change array values based on (positional) entries of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I know changing one array based on another has been discussed many times. However, I fail with a slightly more complicated application:
I have an numpy.ndarray resulting from a dropdown selection in Excel (but that shouldn't really matter):

```
array(['No change', 'Change third value',
       'Change first value', 'Change fourth value'],
      dtype='<U27')
```

And another numpy.ndarray (both arrays could possibly differ regarding their size but there will always be one entry in the first array for each list of the second array) of this form:

```
array([[0.05, 0.07 , 0.04, 0.03, 0.05,
        0.72],
       [0.08, 0.083, **1** , 0.038, 0.05,
        0.70],
       [**1**, 0.17, 0.07, 0.04, 0.03,
        0.31],
       [0.16, 0.14, 0.08, **1**, 0.08,
        0.40]])
```

I now need a way to change the values of the second array to 1 in that place corresponding to the values of the first array, whereby the first entry is relevant for the first list of the second array and so on...(as seen above)

So basically I am looking for a solution that reads the information from the first array and changes the second array accordingly. But I struggle to find a way that changes the right values on the right position.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, create a dictionary to map first, second.... with numeric values. The second would be to loop through each row of `array1` and `array2` and then check if the element of `array1` is  `'No change'` or not. If not, then split the element and get its second part(numeric). Use indexing and change the row of `array2`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change some values in the second array according to the guidance from the first array.

To simplify the problem, you should first construct a function that tells you what the "Natural Language String" means...

Assume, f("Change third value") = 3, f("Change first value") = 1 and so on.
Now consider following pseudocode:

```py
first = ['No change', 'Change third value',
       'Change first value', 'Change fourth value']
second = [[0.05, 0.07 , 0.04, 0.03, 0.05,
        0.72],
       [0.08, 0.083, **1** , 0.038, 0.05,
        0.70],
       [**1**, 0.17, 0.07, 0.04, 0.03,
        0.31],
       [0.16, 0.14, 0.08, **1**, 0.08,
        0.40]]
for cmd, each in zip(first, second):
    each[f(cmd)] = expected_value()
```

The trick here is using zip to combine each item from the first and second array, so you won't mismatch or be hard to match them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For me, that simple f-function is the problem here I think. How would you write this in a general form so that the application via the zip approach proceeds line by line depending on the input from `first`?

Comment: Maybe to be more precise: How do I have to write f(cmd) so that the replacement of the values in 'second' takes place on the corresponding position? Or did I get your approach wrong and this happens via the 'zip'?